# Get MAX value rows from second table on join

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, first one keeps names and second is related to it on in = cid. I need to get only the highest date row from second table, once. Please look below for clearer explanation:

table1 a

```
+----+-------+
| id |  name |
+----+-------+
|  1 | name1 |
|  2 | name2 |
|  3 | name3 |
|  4 | name4 |
|  5 | name5 |
+----+-------+
```

table2 c

```
+----+-------+------------+
| id | cid   | galiojaiki |
+----+-------+------------+
|  1 |    1  | 2015-04-30 |
|  2 |    1  | 2015-09-30 |
|  3 |    1  | 2015-03-10 |
|  4 |    2  | 2015-06-30 |
|  5 |    2  | 2015-07-30 |
|  6 |    3  | 2015-05-11 |
|  7 |    4  | 2015-05-10 |
+----+-------+------------+
```

Expected result:

```
+------------+-------+
| galiojaiki |  name |
+------------+-------+
| 2015-09-30 | name1 |
| 2015-07-30 | name2 |
| 2015-05-11 | name3 |
| 2015-05-11 | name4 |
+------------+-------+
```

My query:

```
SELECT a.*, c.galiojaiki FROM `y6fdt_igym_abonementai` AS a 
INNER JOIN 
( 
    SELECT max(galiojaiki) FROM y6fdt_igym_sutartys
) c
on c.cid= a.id
GROUP BY c.abonementas
```

Comment: So cid is a.id? Could you make that more confusing ? And 4 is 10, not 11 !?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How anout a simple aggregation using MAX?

Something like

```
SELECT a.name, 
MAX(b.galiojaiki) as galiojaiki
FROM `y6fdt_igym_abonementai` AS a INNER JOIN
`y6fdt_igym_sutartys` as b  ON a.ID = b.CID
GROUP BY a.name
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8409/1)